# Write a function named "locate" that gets an array and value and returns true if specified value exist in a multidimentional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example:

```
locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'e'); // should return true
locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'a'); // should return true
locate(['a','b',['c','d',['e']]],'f'); // should return false
```

my solution:

```
var locate = function(arr,value){
  arr=arr.join('').split(',').join('').split('');

  return arr.indexOf(value)!==-1;
}
```

it failed:`Should not find 'three'`

And more:

```
var locate = function(arr,value){
  arr=arr.join('').split(',').join('');

  return arr.indexOf(value)!==-1;
}
```

it's a diffrent result.

Comment: This question needs changes to be useful to others; what problem are you having? That problem should be your title. Also, "Why failed" should be changed to what you're expecting to see and what you're actually seeing.

Comment: Missquoting Obi Wan, "Luke, use the for... loop" (recursion)

Comment: As to "why failed", just because you code passes with the example they gave you doesn't mean it's actually good or correct code. It just means it returns the expected answer for the examples. No doubt they have hidden test cases designed to catch out code that takes short cuts and is not generalized (for example, just hard coding the outputs for a given input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a huge assumption about your inputs. Just because the sample data uses single characters, doesn't mean the actual test data will be single characters.

Your solution just smashes everything down into a string with no delimiters and then explodes it back into an array of single characters. This will fail badly for inputs like `locate(['te', 'st'], 'blah')`, where your solution will destroy the input array, producing something like `['t', 'e', 's', 't']` to search through.

You need to recursively search the array for individual elements that match *exactly*. You're trying to be way too clever with your split/join/split/join stuff.

Comment: i tried it at second sample.an err occured :Should not find 'three'

Comment: Not sure *clever* is the word I would have used. They are also assuming a maximum depth for nesting, which is also "*clever*"

Comment: @MattBurland Depth isn't a problem. Invoking `join('')` on an array of arbitrary depth will invoke `toString` on each nested array, recursively, all the way down. `[1, [2, [3, [4, [5, ....]]]]].join('')` will produce the string `12,3,4,5`. The more direct route that would produce consistent results would be to simply invoke `toString` on the top-level array: `[1, 2, [3, [4, [5, 6, [7], [8]]]]].toString() // => "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"`

Comment: @meagar: I honestly didn't know that `toString` would do that to a nested array. Good to know.